# Unrecognized option "form" under "sonata_doctrine_orm_admin.templates". Available option is "types"

Tags: forms

There is deleted child node `sonata_doctrine_orm_admin.templates.form` since 4.0 version. How was it supposed to deal with it? There is no solution in docs, as i see

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm in process of updating project's libraries.
I had these rows in config:
`sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    templates:
        form:
            - pass_to_twig
`
But now I upgrade sonata_doctrine_orm_admin from 3.3 to 4.8 and there isn't such node as `form`. Where should I place my twig instead?